# How to get higher camera preview fps like snapchat?

Tags: android, camera

On Android,

Anyone have any idea what trick snapchat pulls to get such high fps on their camera preview? I have tried various methods:

- using a textureview instead of surface view
- forcing hardware acceleration
- using lower resolutions
- using different preview formats (YV12 , NV21 drops frames)
- changing focusing mode

None have left me anywhere close to the constant 30fps or maybe even above that snapchat seems to get. I can just about get to the same fps as the stock google camera app, but this isn't great, and mine displays at much lower resolution.

EDIT:

The method used is the same as that used by the official android video recording app. The preview there is of the same image quality and is locked to 30fps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believed they used the android NDK. You can find more information [in android developer](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Using pure C/C++ is faster than JAVA code in performance critical tasks such as image and video processing.

You can also try to improve the performance by compiling the application with another compiler, like [the Intel compiler](http://software.intel.com/en-us/c-compiler-android).

Answer (score 3):

try this it works

```
public void takeSnapPhoto() {
camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        int format = parameters.getPreviewFormat();
        //YUV formats require more conversion
        if (format == ImageFormat.NV21 || format == ImageFormat.YUY2 || format == ImageFormat.NV16) {
            int w = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
            int h = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;
            // Get the YuV image
            YuvImage yuv_image = new YuvImage(data, format, w, h, null);
            // Convert YuV to Jpeg
            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
            ByteArrayOutputStream output_stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yuv_image.compressToJpeg(rect, 100, output_stream);
            byte[] byt = output_stream.toByteArray();
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                // Write to SD Card
                File file = createFileInSDCard(FOLDER_PATH, "Image_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
                //Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(file);
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                outStream.write(byt);
                outStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
        }
    }
});}
```

Comment: Hi Rohit!  I'm a little unclear where you would use this code?  Do you have to open the camera first, or something?  Or - just call this routine??  Cheers!

Comment: Just to be clear - how do you mean "open the camera" in this context?  (Sorry if you don't have time!  :) )  cheers...

Comment: @JoeBlow thanks for adding bounty... I will try to produce a more complete example for you and thanks Rohit for the code!

Comment: @ROHITPARMAR isn't this just going to take one photo when a button is pressed and save it to the sd card?

Comment: No, you can take multiple photos by continuously clicking on a button.